# Using twig variable inside load jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a problem with including twig inside load function of jQuery, here is an example:

```
<!-- src/MyBundle/Ressources/views/index.html.twig -->

{% extends'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="layout"></div>

{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#layout').load("{{ asset('layout/myLayout.html.twig') }}", function(){
                alert($('#link').attr('href'));
            });
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and

```
<!-- web/layout/myLayout.html.twig -->
<a id="link" href="{{ asset('layout/myLayout.html.twig') }}"> link </a>
```

In this example when I load the page, Alert display  {{ asset('layout/myLayout.html.twig') }}  instead of http://localhost/myProject/web/layout/myLayout.html.twig

It is not interpreted as a twig variable, but as the text

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're just loading the twig template file with your ajax load method, so the contents of that file are not being interpreted.  You need to create a route and a controller to render the file 'layout/myLayout.html.twig' and use that in your load method.

For instance if you create a route called `layout_route` and that defines a controller action that renders your `layout/myLayout.html.twig` template:

**Routing:**

```
# routing.yml
layout_route:
    path: /layout #or whatever you choose
    defaults: { _controller : MyBundle:Layout:index }
```

**Controller:**

```
// MyBundle/Controller/LayoutController
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('MyBundle::myLayout.html.twig', array();
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#layout').load("{{ url('layout_route') }}", function(){
    alert($('#link').attr('href'));
});
```